# How to watch a child component data not coming from a parent component (Angularjs 1.5 or 1.6)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following codes:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', [])
  // navigation template
app.component('onChanges', {
      bindings: {
        name: '<'
      },
      template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.greeting}}</h1><br><h2>{{origin}}</h2> ',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.origin = 'international';
        this.$onChanges = function(obj) {
          if (obj.name && this.name) {
            var prefix;
            (obj.name.currentValue.toLowerCase() === 'thomas') ?
            prefix = 'Howdy ': prefix = 'Hello ';
            this.greeting = prefix + this.name;
            (prefix === 'Hello ' || !prefix) ? $scope.origin = 'american': $scope.origin = 'australian';
          }

          // if the name is undefined clear greeting

          if (!this.name) {
            this.greeting = ''
          }
        };

        $scope.$watch('$scope.origin', function() {
          console.log("I am here");
        })

        }
      });
```

**Modified Post**: I use $scope.$watch to monitor the change of $scope.origin. What wrong did I do?
Please try this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DDZeTHQIji4FJnyhpQAJ?p=preview

**Original Post**:
My problem is a common problem for those using Angular 1.5 or 1.6 components, but surprisingly, I can not find a SO question/answer relating to this.

In this case, $ctrl.origin is not data from the parent component while $ctrl.name is passed to the child component from the parent component.

To my understanding:
$onChanges function can only watch $ctrl.name - data coming into the component from an external source e.g parent component.

My question: How do I watch the change of local data of a component like $ctrl.origin - data not passed from a parent component? An example might be useful.

Please share your thoughts on how to do it.

Here is my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DDZeTHQIji4FJnyhpQAJ?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the AngularJS:

```
$onChanges(changesObj) - Called whenever one-way bindings are updated. The
changesObj is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that
have changed, and the values are an object of the form { currentValue,
previousValue, isFirstChange() }. Use this hook to trigger updates within 
a component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation 
of the outer value.
```

So first make sure your bindings are one-way and the bindings exist (yours doesn't in this case, so $onChanges won't work).

As for watching variables from other scopes, I believe $watch is capable:

```
$scope.$watch(
  () => { // Old variable value; },
  '$ctrl.origin' => {
    console.log('something changed on variable', variable-name, 'blah');
  }
);
```

Comment: So in my case, I have to use $watch just like in Angular 1.4, right?

Comment: I modify the post a little bit above.  Using $watch but does not work.  Please see my Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/DDZeTHQIji4FJnyhpQAJ?p=preview What wrong with $watch ('$scope.origin', function....